# How to simplify multithreaded design using asio?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost-asio

This is long question. **TL;DR**: I don't know how to properly design programs using asio.

People have written GUI wrappers for CLI utilities. I am writing a "proxy" for such a utility that relays the commands issued by the GUI to another copy of the utility running on a remote computer (via another "proxy" on the remote computer).

I am currently using asio for socket I/O, but am using a simple loop in `main()` to perform blocking reads from `stdin` (async I/O not possible on `stdin` & friends on Windows). I have tried to decouple everything by using a simple pub/sub mechanism. Message subscribers run on their own threads and receive messages from a `std::deque` via a `std::condition_variable`. I currently have the following I/O related classes:

- *SocketServer:* Runs on own thread, creates an `asio::io_service`, binds to & listens on a port, and accepts remote connections.
- *SocketClient:* Creates an `asio::io_service`, connects to remote host & provides password.
- *SocketConnection:* Gets created by SocketServer or SocketClient. Authenticates remote host (server-only), reads from socket, and writes to socket on receiving `SocketOutputMessage` (on separate thread).
- *ConsoleWriter:* Runs on own thread, writes to `stdout` upon receiving `ConsoleOutputMessage`.

To me the major flaw in this design is that there are **too many threads!** SocketServer needs its own thread because of blocking call to `asio::io_service::run()`. Similarly, ConsoleWriter is on its own thread to ensure all writes to `stdout` occur on the same thread. I don't want yet another thread for SocketConnection but need it as a consequence of pub/sub. (I want message to always be dispatched on the *receiver's* thread)

Please could someone provide me with suggestions on how to streamline the above design (and hopefully reduce the no. of threads required)? To this end, are there any asio features I should know about? Please provide some sample code and/or links to relevant sites or SO answers if you can.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you create two io_services, the first one (which you can dispatch in a thread) should be used for all socket communication.) And the second (dispatching on the main thread) should handle the console activity.

For example:

```
main()
{
  // Run the network service
  std::thread service([]() { net_service.run(); });
  // Now run the console service
  console_service.run();
}
```

To communicate between the two services, use the `io_service::post()` operation. This posts a handler onto the given io service which is executed in that context. For example.

```
client_socket.async_read_some(_data, [](...) {
  // Now you have the data and you want to print it..
  console_service.post([=]() { std::cout << "message " << _data << std::endl; });
});
```

So now when you read something from the `client_socket`, you post that data to the console service - note it's important that either you copy the data or if you want to avoid the copies, create some separate queue like you have and simply use the `post()` mechanism to notify the other io_service.

NOTE: The other answer mentions `poll()`, this will cause the context to spin as it will return immediately if there is nothing to complete.

Answer (score 0):

io_serivce.poll() just runs the current events and then returns, I call it repeatedly instead of having a thread just for that.

You could avoid having consolewriter on it's own thread by locking around the writing part, by some form of lock/mutex/spinnlock/...

If you use async_read() instead of read() you supply a callback that's called whenever there's data to be read. That way you let asio handle the threads and you don't need to worry about it.